# How to customize the JavaDoc template for method in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, methods, javadoc

I am using Android Studio 1.1.0. I was searching and trying to customize the **JavaDoc for method** in Android Studio. When I type `/**` and press `enter` before any function I get the following and I want to **customize** this template.

```
/**
 * 
 * @param some_args
 * @return
 */
 public long addData(long some_args){
```

Before I do modification for **Class** template using the following process.

1. Go to `File >> Settings`. Under IDE Settings `File and Code Template` then `Class`. I see the `#parse("File Header.java")` on the right side.

[image]

2. So I change that file in the following way:Go to the tab `Includes`and modify the template on the right side.

[image]

Now I can see documentation for all newly created classes according to what I have modified for `Class` like below:

```
/**
 * @author Siddiqui Noor
 * @version 1.3.0
 * @desc Technical Director, RFsoftLab.
 * @link www.SiddiquiNoor.com
 * @created on 20-Aug-15
 * @updated on 20-Aug-15
 * @modified by
 * @updated on
 * @since 1.0
 */
```

Does someone know the way to create something like that for method/function using the Settings interfaces like my above images.

Thank you guys for heading into this.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to customize the JavaDoc template. The tags are generated according to the signature of the method (parameter types, return type and exceptions).